# Wordpress custom taxonomy template doesn't display archive page

Tags: wordpress

I register new custom taxonomy named "portfolio" using Custom Post Type UI plugin. Then create template taxonomy-portfolio.php and loop posts, expecting that when I type mysite.com/portfolio in browser, will get it. It works only when I get term of this taxonomy, I see this template, otherwise redirecting on 404. How can I use taxonomy template for archive?

Comment: Try visiting the permalinks settings page, this rebuilds the rewrite rules and usually solves issues with 404 on custom post types and taxonomies .

Comment: No, it isn't work for me. I was think that taxonomy archive and it's terms has the same template, but wordpress doesn't know about root of tax, like /category or /tag and redirect me back to index. I solve this creating a page with right slug. Another way to do this it is to use hooks before query parse.